# WPF: Window SetBounds

Tags: wpf

I used SetBounds method in Windows.Forms instead of Left,Top,Width,Height properties assignment because each time I assign value that changes location property - window changes it's position. Left,Top,Width,Height assignment causes window to move 4 times while SetBounds move windows once (better UI experience, no window hesitation).

When I migrate to WPF I found that there is no SetBounds method and it looks like I have to change window size and position step by step.

What is the best way to change WPF window position in one window move?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SetBounds` is not available in WPF, but you can easily P/invoke the `SetWindowPos` API:

```
    private IntPtr _handle;
    private void SetBounds(int left, int top, int width, int height)
    {
        if (_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            _handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

        SetWindowPos(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, left, top, width, height, 0);
    }

    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
        int x,
        int y,
        int cx,
        int cy,
        uint uFlags);
```

The `Left`, `Top`, `Width` and `Height` dependency properties will automatically be updated to reflect the new bounds.

Comment: Thank you, @Thomas! It's so strange that WPF fathers threw out SetBounds method. It's nearly unbelievable for me that we had to apply dirty hacks to such a nice technology, developed to abstract us from Windows widgets.